# How to print multiline ASCII art in Go?

Tags: go

I am trying to print out ASCII art text in my Go application but I have failed so far and I need some help.

I took in text to be printed out as ASCII from std.in and converted it to array of ASCII number format.

ie: "abc" to [97 98 99]

I also created a map of ASCII art multiline strings from a text file. Each string has height of 8 lines.

[image: ASCII art exclamation mark]

ie: map[32:       , 33: ASCII-ART-EXCLAMATION MARK]

**NB! Value of key 32 is space therefore, 8 blank spaces. All the values in the map are multiline strings. Like in the screenshot.**

Now, I need to print out user's text in a ASCII art format. First I created a 2d array of strings by splitting values inside the map using new line. Then, I added extra paddings to fix each items length to 8 back again. (I am not sure if this approach is correct tho)

```
var lines [][]string

for i, _ := range asciiSlice {
    lines = append(lines, strings.Split(asciiMap[asciiSlice[i]], "\n"))
}

// Add padding offset to fix the height.
for i, _ := range lines {
    missingPadSize := 8 - len(lines[i])
    for j := 0; j < missingPadSize; j++ {
        lines[i] = append(lines[i], " ")
    }
}
```

Output of example test run for the string "abc":

`` [[  __ _  / _` | | (_| |  \__,_|        ] [ _ | | | |__ | '_ \ | |_) | |_.__/    ] [  ___  / __| | (__  \___|        ]] ``

At this point maybe I can loop over this 2d array and then append values into one array and join the strings by the empty space. However, I cannot figure out the loop.

With the loop I managed to construct the ASCII texts printed in new lines rather than next to each other.

Expected output:
[image: expected output]

Can someone please help?